# Maximum Repeated Word in Large file of size 30 gb best approach

Tags: java, large-files, fileinputstream

I am able to run the program for small piece of file but if very large size of file  is there and we don't have that much memory  then we will run out of memory exception what would be the best approach for this problem so that it can be done in memory with below same algo

```
package com.java.ds.arrays;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class FileRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        HashMap<String, Integer> wordCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            // Creating BufferedReader object

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ser.txt"));

            // Reading the first line into currentLine

            String currentLine = reader.readLine();

            while (currentLine != null) {
                // splitting the currentLine into words

                String[] words = currentLine.toLowerCase().split(" ");

                // Iterating each word

                for (String word : words) {
                    // if word is already present in wordCountMap, updating its count

                    if (wordCountMap.containsKey(word)) {
                        wordCountMap.put(word, wordCountMap.get(word) + 1);
                    }

                    else {
                        wordCountMap.put(word, 1);
                    }
                }


                currentLine = reader.readLine();
            }

            // Getting the most repeated word and its occurrence

            String mostRepeatedWord = null;

            int count = 0;

            Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = wordCountMap.entrySet();

            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
                if (entry.getValue() > count) {
                    mostRepeatedWord = entry.getKey();

                    count = entry.getValue();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The most repeated word in input file is : " + mostRepeatedWord);

            System.out.println("Number Of Occurrences : " + count);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close(); // Closing the reader
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have much experience in working such large file. 
One Idea I can think of

1. reading this file into chunks of 1GB say
   then find frequency count of each member in this 
   and write into  another file
2. then again read the next chunks of 1GB 
   find frequence count of each member 
   write into another file
3. merge these two files and get key value pair

Repeat step 1 2 and 3

But now sure this would be appropriate approach if its how would i code this

Comment: You would only run out of memory if the "words" are random sequence of characters, thus producing a huge amount of keys in the map. If the file contains normal text, there shouldn't be that many keys. Even assuming 1,000,000 different words, with an average size of 10 characters, that would only a few megabytes of memory. That's assuming of course that the file doesn't contain huge lines (since you read line by line)

Comment: Indeed, if you're using buffers, you can read through the whole file. You should just make sure to have enough memory to contain the Map of word + occurencies